# "Trying to get property 'listaOrdenes' of non-object" error returning json

Tags: php, json, laravel, properties

I have the following problem when returning to JSON from a function in PHP, when trying to read some of the properties of JSON, the following error returns to me.

```
  public function ObtenerListadoOrdenes(){
    try {
        $existeNueva = false;
        //OBTENEMOS LA LISTA DE ORDENES.
        $orderList = json_decode(CallApiRest::CallAPI('GET', $this->url.'/orders/get/list', false, $this->token));

        foreach($orderList as $item){
            $orderlist = OrderList::find($item->orderNumber);

            if ($orderlist == null){
                $existeNueva = true;

                $orderlist = new OrderList;

                $orderlist->orderNumber = $item->orderNumber;
                $orderlist->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($item->date));

                $orderlist->save();
            }
        }

        $tempArray = array('existeNueva'=>$existeNueva, 'listaOrdenes'=>$orderList);

        return $tempArray;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

The error return in the next code.
**return $listado->listaOrdenes;**

```
public function index()
    {
        $laudusApi = new LaudusApiConnect;
        $listado = $laudusApi->ObtenerListadoOrdenes();

        return $listado->listaOrdenes;
    }
```

**The Error is : Trying to get property 'listaOrdenes' of non-object**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `$laudusApi->ObtenerListadoOrdenes();` is an array. In PHP arrays should be accessed as such: `$listado['listaOrdenes'];`